# MongoDB auto_reconnect doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, mongoskin

I'm using mongoskin as a wrapper to the native mongodb driver, auto_reconnect doesn't seem to work.

I'm creating the database:

```
var db = mongo.db(serverUrl, {
    database: database,
    auto_reconnect: true,
    safe: true
});
```

I added a query on connection close to test it:

```
db.on('close', function(err) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        db.collection('users').findOne({short_id: '123'}, console.log);
    }, 5000)
});
```

immediately after running the node process i'm killing and starting mongod, I'm getting '[Error: no open connections]' as the query result.

doesn't it suppose to auto_reconnect on connection lose ? or its trying to auto_reconnect immediately on connection close but mongod isn't up yet ?

can I reconnect manually or do I need to create a new server ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest node-mongodb-native (1.2.11) driver and it should work as you expect it to.

Comment: I'm using Mongoskin as a wrapper, but updated it's package.json under node_modules/mongoskin to `"mongodb": "1.2.11"` and run `npm install`. I'm still getting the no open connections error with the same test.

Comment: Why is auto_reconnect set to default to false? Any ideas on why they decided that?

Comment: @doremi, that's exactly what brought me to this question to begin with.